# RxJS state management

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

How to save state of React App with RxJS Observable. When I refresh the page after adding new item to CRUD app, it is not saving new item in the list, new addedly item disappears. By the logic of app, new item should be saved in local storage after page refresh.

Comment: Could you post a minimum set of code what you want and what you expect?

Comment: yeh we need some code, give us a chance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could it

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;
const { BehaviorSubject, of, operators: { switchMap, tap } } = rxjs;

const mockLocalStorage = {
  values: `["one","two","three"]`,
  getItem(key) {
    return this.values
  },
  setItem(key, value) {
    this.values = value
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const ref = useRef(new BehaviorSubject(undefined));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = ref.current
      .pipe(switchMap(_ => 
        of(JSON.parse(mockLocalStorage.getItem('key'))))
        )
      .subscribe(values => {
        setList(values);
      })
    
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
      
  }, [])
  
  const onChange = ({key, target: {value}}) => setValue(value)
  
  const addItem = ({key, target: {value}}) => {
    if (key !== 'Enter') {
      return;
    }
  
    const state = [...list, value];
    mockLocalStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(state))
    ref.current.next(state);
    setValue('');
  }

return <div>
  {list.map(item => <div key={item}>{item}</div>)}
  <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} onKeyDown={addItem} placeholder="Enter item and press enter..."/>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
</script>
<div id="root"></div>
```